# How to recreate TpmPublic instance from result of TpmPublic.GetTpm2BRepresentation()

Tags: c#, tpm

I am able to store the endorsement key from a TPM in a byte array using the following code (referencing TSS.NET):

```cs
TpmPublic ekPub = GetEndorsementKey();

byte[] ek = ekPub.GetTpm2BRepresentation();
```

I have tried this, but I don't know how to get from a `Tpm2bPublicKeyRsa` instance to an instance of `TpmPublic`:

```cs
Tpm2bPublicKeyRsa temp = new Tpm2bPublicKeyRsa(ek)
```

Notes:

- I want to pass the endorsement key around as a byte array because it's convenient to Base64 encode the array for copy/paste.
- I want to get back to an instance of `TpmPublic` so that I can transform that key (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56306558/232566)) into something I can use it server side in .NET (without a TPM) .

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to use the `GetTpmRepresentation` method:

```cs
TpmPublic ekPub = GetEndorsementKey();

byte[] ekPubBytes = ekPub.GetTpmRepresentation();
```

That makes it easy to get the `TpmPublic` instance back using the marshaller:

```cs
var mashaller = new Marshaller(ekPubBytes);

TpmPublic ekPub = m.Get<TpmPublic>();
```